# regex: replace string if it's between two spaces, leave unchanged if not

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to remove a string A that exists in another string B only if string A is between two spaces.

```
string A = "e"
string B = "the fifth letter is e "
```

Example for replacing 'e' : `"the fifth letter is e "`  --> `"the fifth letter is"`

Comment: I don't get your example. Which one is A and B here? Are there restrictions? like the string being surrounded by more than one space? In your example e is not between two spaces. What is the replacement? removing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > a = "the fifth letter is e "
 => "the fifth letter is e " 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > print a.gsub(/\se\s/,"")
the fifth letter is => nil
```

Edited the answer after you edited the question. A possible regular expression to find an "e" character between two space characters is `/\se\s/`. In this case I'm replacing it with an empty string `""`. You can use [`gsub`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001538) which returns a copy of the string or [`gsub!`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001545) to modify the original string.

**UPDATE:** Since you edited the question again, here's un updated answer:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > a = "e"
 => "e" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > b = "the fifth letter is e "
 => "the fifth letter is e " 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > print b.gsub(/\s#{a}\s/,"")
the fifth letter is => nil
```

Comment: Yeah, it is wrong because the question is constantly being changed, so I should be constantly updating the answer...

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need regex for this.

```
a = "e"
b = "the fifth letter is e "
c = b.gsub(" " << a << " ", "")
```

PS. In Ruby it's a constant if it begins with an uppercase letter. DS.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'the fifth letter is e'
thing = 'e'
str.sub! /\s+#{thing}\s+/, ''
```

Comment: It works for me. Of course, I've edited the post a few times in between.... (Standard FGitW technique, y'know? ;-))